# how to turn off autocomplete for an input in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input for getting password from user :
`<input name="Password" id="Password" required/>`
in most devices browser will try to autocomplete the password input ( based on saved passwords ),
but lets say we don't want this behavior , **so how could we turn off autocomplete for an input? **

after searching and trying to turn off autocomplete found this solution,
set attribute autocomplete to off :
`<input name="Password" id="Password" required autocomplete="off"/>`
but it didn't work, when page loads this will happen , i tried JavaScript too but it didn't worked neither
`$("#Password").val('')`

Comment: does [this](https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/360164708c3b326bd1c8?permalink_comment_id=3793032) help

Comment: i have tried that solution , it kept autocompleting for password input and i also dont want to disable autocompleting for all inputs

Comment: If you mean the behavior of Chrome which fully completes the login fields, That is not controled by HTML tags. That is the separate behavior of the brower which overrides the HTML rules by user settings.

Comment: Yes I meant login fields and this answer solved my problem 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78067299/23490246
I think they have change autocomplete="off" to autocomplete="new-password" in chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for Chrome is to add autocomplete="new-password" to the input type password. Please check the example below.

Example:

```html
<form name="myForm"" method="post">
   <input name="user" type="text" />
   <input name="pass" type="password" autocomplete="new-password" />
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Chrome always autocomplete the data if it finds a box of type password, just enough to indicate for that box autocomplete = "new-password".

Note: make sure with CTRL + F5 that your changes take effect. Many times, browsers save the page in the cache.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 ways you could do this:-

1. Add an attribute for the input field i.e, `autocomplete = "off"`

Example:-

```html
<form>
   <input type="text" />
   <input type="password" autocomplete = "off"/>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

2. Add an attribute for the entire form i.e, `autocomplete = "off"`

Example:-

```html
<form method="post" autocomplete="off">
   <input type="text" />
   <input type="password" autocomplete = "off"/>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

3. If the above 2 didn't work then, set autocomplete = "new-password" to the input field. This should definitely prevent the browser from saving the input data.

Example:-

```html
<form method="post">
   <input type="text" />
   <input type="password" autocomplete = "new-password"/>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The first 2 solutions might not work since modern browsers provide a feature to save passwords i.e, they may ask to save the login credentials which will prevent the `autocomplete = "off"` to act.

For Reference:-
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion